# Creating Installer for DLL that installs .NET Framework

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2012, dll, visual-studio-2015

I've made a DLL in Visual Studio which is used by a Java application to use the Windows C++ serial communication API. The problem is that when distributing this Java application and DLL to those who will use it, they must have .NET Framework 4.5.1 Runtime or later installed for the Java program to be able to load the DLL.

I've done a bit of research on Visual Studio's ClickOnce wizard, but I can't seem to find a straight forward answer. The ideal installation method would be to have a setup.exe which, when run, would check the version of .NET installed on the computer and automatically download the correct version if needed.

Comment: Google it "msdn redist .net 4.5.1" : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek(v=vs.110).aspx  Installers for .NET Framework

Comment: Windows. Microsoft. Installers. Excuse me if I laugh...